# parent-child relationships with recursive SQL does not work with date ranges

Tags: mysql, recursion, parent-child, hierarchy, date-range

My objective is to create a query that shows the person hierarchy for each year. This will be displayed on a "path" generated column with delimited ids. For example, path 1\2\3\4\5 means that 5 is a child of 4, 4 is a child of 3, 3 is a child of 2 and 2 is a child of 1. These relationships must match related date ranges. The tricky part is that the ranges may be different between children and parents so the joins are complex.

I have this table that holds person relationships for date ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE `persons_x_roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

where parent_id is the FK from a table persons.

The top person in the hierarchy has him/herself as parent (I know it's not perfect design and that it should have parent_id = NULL). Nevertheless, I have the following recursive SQL to get the hierarchies:

```
WITH RECURSIVE roles_path AS (
    SELECT
        persons_x_roles.id,
        person_id,
        role_from,
        YEAR ( role_from ) AS effective_year,
        role_to,
        parent_id,
        1 AS depth,
        cast(
        person_id AS VARCHAR ( 32 )) AS person_path 
    FROM
        persons_x_roles 
    WHERE
        person_id = 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT
        child_roles.id,
        child_roles.person_id,
        child_roles.role_from,
        YEAR ( child_roles.role_from ) AS effective_year,
        child_roles.role_to,
        child_roles.parent_id,
        parent_roles.depth + 1,
        CONCAT( parent_roles.person_path, '\\', child_roles.person_id ) 
    FROM
        roles_path AS parent_roles
        LEFT JOIN persons_x_roles AS child_roles ON (
            parent_roles.person_id = child_roles.parent_id 
            AND parent_roles.role_from <= child_roles.role_from 
            AND IFNULL( parent_roles.role_to, CURRENT_DATE ) >= IFNULL( child_roles.role_to, IFNULL( parent_roles.role_to, CURRENT_DATE ) ) 
        ) 
    WHERE
        child_roles.person_id != 1 
        AND child_roles.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
    ) SELECT
    * 
FROM
    roles_path 
ORDER BY
    person_path
```

The persons_x_roles table, for person 14073, has these entries:

```
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (14073, 14073, '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31', NULL);
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (25698, 14073, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', 26);
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (45195, 14073, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', 26);
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (54710, 14073, '2019-01-01', NULL, 26);


select * from persons_x_roles where person_id=14073


14073   14073       5   2016-01-01  2016-12-31  [NULL]
25698   14073       5   2017-01-01  2017-12-31  26
45195   14073       5   2018-01-01  2018-12-31  26
54710   14073       5   2019-01-01  [NULL]      26
```

For the parent person (26), it has these:

```
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (26, 26, '2016-01-01', '2019-12-31', 6);
INSERT INTO `visitsmgmt_jpa`.`persons_x_roles`(`id`, `person_id`, `role_from`, `role_to`, `parent_id`) VALUES (69338, 26, '2020-01-01', NULL, 4);

select * from persons_x_roles where person_id=26

26      26  1   4   2016-01-01  2019-12-31  6
69338   26  1   4   2020-01-01  [NULL]      4
```

However, if I run the recursive SELECT for the child person, I'm missing some rows:

```
select * from persons_x_roles_path where person_id=14073

45195   14073   2018-01-01  2018    2018-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
25698   14073   2017-01-01  2017    2017-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
54710   14073   2019-01-01  2019    [NULL]      26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
```

The missing row is for 2020. While the parent (26) has one closed-ended record for 2019 and one open-ended record for 2020, the child has an open-ended record starting 2019.

So, I would expect the results to be like this:

```
45195   14073   2018-01-01  2018    2018-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
25698   14073   2017-01-01  2017    2017-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
54710   14073   2019-01-01  2019    2019-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
69338   14073   2020-01-01  2020    2020-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
```

or

```
45195   14073   2018-01-01  2018    2018-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
25698   14073   2017-01-01  2017    2017-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
54710   14073   2019-01-01  2019    2019-12-31  26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
69338   14073   2020-01-01  2020    [NULL]      26  5   1\2\6\26\14073
```

Comment: Provide some sample data (8-10 rows) and desired output for this data. Explain the logic of your query in details.

Comment: just did, hope it helps

Comment: Where `'1\2\6\'` is taken from? such values are absent in provided sample data. Shown desired output must match the data completely.

Comment: *`select * from persons_x_roles where person_id=14073`* The output does not match previous INSERT - excess column with values `5` is printed.

Comment: And you have not provided the task itself (and detailed logic for shown query with recursive CTE)... PS. Sample data may be provided as [online fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64368975c4500c2c0b02396b1e9a8a81). Very useful for testing purposes. PPS. It is unclear why `person_id=26` have different `parent_id` values in different rows.

Comment: 1\2\6 is generated in the query, same as '5'. They are not fields from the original table.

Comment: Ok. But where is the description of needed logic?

Comment: I thought it was clear. But you are right. Just added objective at the top

Comment: *My objective is to create a query that shows the person hierarchy for each year.* Well, it is really clear. The only problem. Imagine that at some hierarchy step we meet some (intermediate) parent which have no row for the year specified for initial child row. Does we must to stop the hierarchy building on this step? Or maybe we must use the data for closest previous year for which the data is present in the table? or we must use some another logic for the hierarchy chain building?

Comment: If the intermediate does not have a row, they must have  an open-ended previous row that's still valid (null end date) for the respective rows of the other persons.

Comment: Does we may assume that for each year of the child there exists a row for its parent with the same year? and there is no cases when, for example, for a child id=1234 in 2010 the parent is id=4321, but this parent have the rows starting from 2011 only?

Comment: Yes, a parent is assumed to have an active record that covers the child's period. Otherwise  the chain must break. But keep in mind that a parent may have an older record ('from' date is earlier that child's 'from' date) .

Comment: Please investigate the logic in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f5b9bab7719b0f42901817976f0f9a5).

Comment: I tried to run it, it's been more than 20 minutes now and hasn't finished.

Comment: You'd check the correctness of the logic, and maybe test on some tiny data array... this code is not optimal, this is only a step to solving.

Comment: Logic is correct apart from the fact that I don't see a "current" (2021 or NULL or 9999) row. Also, if it makes things faster, I could have a year table with years 2016-2046 (30 years should be more than enough).